# Option to Tell a Friend

Tags: civicontribute, contribution-page

When I click "tell a friend" and submit my friend's name and email after I've made a contribution on our contribution page I get error, "Supervised Rule for Individual Doesn't Exist" -- what does this mean? How can I fix this so our contributors can share information about our organization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CiviCRM is telling you that there is no "supervised" rule configured for the Individual contact type - it doesn't know how to check that those "friends" are new unique contacts and not existing donors/members/contributors etc.

There's some information on [deduping and merging contacts](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/deduping-and-merging/) in the [CiviCRM User Guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/)

In particular please check that you have a supervised rule configured for individuals as seen in the screenshot on the first linked page.

Comment: does it make sense that Supervised is actually involved - wouldn't this be an Unsupervised Rule? so while the fact one is missing, is it actually being used. If it is using 'supervised' that seems to imply that if i enter an email then i will be told if it already is in the system, and i dn't think we should be divulging that info at that point should we

Comment: I actually didn't have either an unsupervised or a supervised rule for individuals. I just made both and tell a friend worked! Can't say which was responsible for it tho.

Comment: I’ll do some testing @petednz-fuzion and work out which and make sure we’re not disclosing!